# Neo4j: How to filter out nodes from a list of IDs?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

I am trying to "select all posts" and exclude specific nodes that are in an array of IDs (post authors). With SQL you can use `NOT IN (1, 2, 3)`. How can I create a CYPHER query to do this?

```
Post  <-- author --  User
 - ID                 - ID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly the same as SQL ;)

```
MATCH (author)-[:author]->(post:Post)
WHERE NOT(ID(author) IN {id_list})
RETURN DISTINCT post
```

Since you tagged the question as Neo4j.rb:

```
User.as(:author).posts.where('NOT(ID(author) IN ?)', [1,2,3])
```

In newer versions of Neo4j.rb:

```
User.as(:author).posts.where_not('ID(author) IN ?', [1,2,3])
```

You didn't mention what kind of ids, so I default to Neo4j IDs, but keep in mind that those can be recycled so they aren't for long term usage as reference.

**EDIT:**

Your comment made be realize that perhaps a better way to go about it is:

```
User.where_not(id: ids).posts
```

It should translate the `id` to whatever you use for `id_property` (`uuid` by default).

Comment: Oh, I guess I should clarify, I have a Neo4j.rb `has_many` relationship on a model. So I don't know if mapping over that list to fetch the `neo_id` is the way to go or not?

Comment: If you map over the association you'll pull all of the data for the nodes.  If you only need the id you can `object.association.pluck(:uuid)` (if you're using the default `uuid` identifier from ActiveNode) and then do `.where_not('author.uuid IN ?', ids)`.

Comment: I notice that you are creating the Ruby query from the User instead of from the Post. I am trying to write this query from a container of posts. Is there a way to do this like `container.posts.author.where_not(id: ids).then_return_the_posts`?

Comment: Yeah, certainly: `container.posts(:post).author.where_not(id: ids).pluck(:post)` (that might need to be `.pluck('DISTINCT post')` BTW)

Comment: It is in the documentation here: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/6.0.x/QueryClauseMethods.html#where-not but perhaps it should be in a more prominent place as part of some examples.